# How to bind or register control's command and property to the view that uses this control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have an **Edit** button in the view, and it is binded to **EditAppointmentCommand** inside the viewmodel which is easy. like this:

```
<AppBarButton Click="OnBottomAppBarButtonClicked"
            Command="{Binding EditAppointmentCommand}"
            Icon="Edit"
            IsEnabled="{Binding CanEditAppointment}"
            Label="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Edit, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                      ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Edit, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```

However, inside the view, there is a pop up control(it's an individual seperate xaml) which also has the same **Edit** button and should work exactly the same way as the Edit button inside the view. I'm thinking about how to bind the button inside the control to **EditAppointmentCommand** in the viewmodel(like the two buttons shares the **EditAppointmentCommand**). Or it is a bad way to share binding? Any advice

The situation is like this: You can edit an item in summary view, but you should also be able to edit that item in the detail view. But the detail pop is an separate control.  The button inside the summary view has been binded to summary viewmodel, how about the button inside the detail view?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm following your workflow, *but*... if your pop-up's `EditCommand` is `public`, you could just set it to the parent's `EditCommand` before showing. Again, I'm not sure if this is what you're alluding to.

Comment: @OhBeWise Thanks. Sorry for my poor explanation. I don't have EditCommand for pop-up yet. I just have EditCommand in viewmodel (which is for the button inside the view). And I want my pop-up also binded to that EditCommand, is it clear now? Thank you so much!

Comment: @OhBeWise I just edited it. The situation is like this:  You can edit an item in summary view, but you should also be able to edit that item in the detail view. But the detail pop is an separate control.

Comment: If the summary view is the only location the detail view can be shown from, then I stick with my original suggestion to set the detail's EditCommand to the summary's EditCommand.  But if the detail view can be shown from other views, that one I'm not sure about.

Comment: @OhBeWise I got some problem when trying to set detail's EditCommand to the summary's EditCommand. I tried this  {binding summary.EditCommand} in detailview.xaml but failed, and I tried EditCommand = SummaryViewModel.EditCommand also failed(I did used that namespace). I'm wondering what is the correct way to set the detail's EditCommand to the summary's EditCommand. Thank you so much!

Comment: In `SummaryViewModel`, if it has or ever creates an instance of `DetailsViewModel` and does a `.Show` or `.ShowDialog` on it, then whenever that instance is created I would just set it there: `detailsViewModel.EditCommand = this.EditCommand;`

Comment: I see. I will give it a shot, thank you!